# Having a problem with glmnet and making a matrix?

Tags: r, model, probability, prediction, glmnet

How do I fix this? This is the code I wrote before. Do the number of observations have to be equal? Would appreciate any help!

```
DATA4=policeexcel2[,c("age", "gender", "raceethnicity", "month", "city","state", "latitude", "longitude", "tract_ce", "cause", "armed", "pop", "share_white", "share_hispanic", "share_black", "p_income", "h_income", "county_income", "comp_income")]

y1<-DATA4$share_white
x1<- model_matrix(DATA4, share_white~.*.)[,-1]
var.names1=names(x1)
dim(x1)

set.seed(216)
cvmod.0=cv.glmnet(y=y1,x=as.matrix(x1),alpha=0)
```

Error in glmnet(x, y, weights = weights, offset = offset, lambda = lambda,  :    number of observations in y (467) not equal to the number of rows of x (461)

Comment: you probably have some missing values. Try `DATA4 <- na.omit(DATA4)` as the second line of your code (i.e. after defining `DATA4` but before doing anything else)

Comment: Please provide a sample dataset otherwise it will be very difficult to help you out. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/6123824